# Increased Code Cache size for Java 7, ReservedCodeCacheSize needs to be twice as big as Java 6

Tags: java, java-7

I'm moving an app from Java 6 to Java 7, after switching to Java 7 the Code Cache usage is significantly higher. On Java 6 my app would use 160mb, it's now using more than 250mb. Is this normal?

My solution will probably just be to increase the size of the code cache but I'm trying to understand why this changed. Is this common with Java 7?

Comment: 32 bit to 64 bit?  Did you change operating systems.

Comment: No, the OS is the same, 64 bit.

Comment: and the jdk is also the same?  64 vs 32

Comment: Both JVM's are 64 bit.

Comment: Although asked a long time ago: Any chance, your Java 7 usese tiered compilation? Java 6 did not and tiered compilation uses up a lot of code cache...